# selection sort recursion calling

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, selection

> I was studying recursion problem 
>   I was going to call it, but it shows like this

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class BinarySearch {
public static int binarySearch(int [] list, int key){
    int low = 0;
    int high = list.length -1;
    return binarySearch(list, key, low ,high);
}
public static int binarySearch(int [] list, int key, int low, int high){
    if(low > high){
        return (-low -1);}
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if(key < list[mid])
        return binarySearch(list, key, low, mid - 1);
    else if(key == list[mid])
        return mid;
    else
        return binarySearch(list, key, mid + 1, high);
}
public static void main (String [] args){
    int [] list = {'1', '2','4','5'};
    binarySearch(list, 4);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));

}
```

}

> output : [49, 50, 52, 53]

what should I do to make it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing characters in integer array: -

```
int [] list = {'1', '2','4','5'};
```

So, the values you obtained is the ASCII code for `1, 2, 4, 5` respectively. Due to this, your `binarySearch` method would not be able to find the value `4` ever. As, it is not exactly there. Remove those single quotes around your values.

Secondly, you are not printing the `return value` of `binarySearch` method: -

```
binarySearch(list, 4);
```

should be: -

```
System.out.println(binarySearch(list, 4));
```

Comment: @BenMinchanJun.. Ah! Thank you for that. I like to spend some time on SO. This keeps me busy, and prevents my mind from getting Rusty. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You added to the list characters values.

Toggle the single quotes like this and it should be fine

```
{1,2,4,5};
```

So in your given case you are storing ascii values of the chars "1", "2", "3"  and "4"

Answer (score 0):

As Rohit points out, you are taking advantage of `char` type being a numeral type.

You can declare your "list" as `char[]` and it should fix it, or use number literals.